# How to make g++ require a standard `main`?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

In particular, how can g++ be made to reject this invalid-as-standard-C++ code:

```
main(){}
```

?

I'm using MinGW g++ 6.2.0, but I imagine an answer will apply to all currently used variants of g++.

---

Example of what I've tried:

```
[C:\my\temp]
> g++ --version | find "++"
g++ (i686-win32-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.2.0

[C:\my\temp]
> type foo.cpp
main() {}

[C:\my\temp]
> dir /b
foo.cpp

[C:\my\temp]
> g++ foo.cpp -Wall -Wextra -Wreturn-type -pedantic

[C:\my\temp]
> dir /b
a.exe
foo.cpp

[C:\my\temp]
> _
```

---

Version info with verbose compiler output:

```
C:\my\temp]
> g++ -v --version
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
g++ (i686-win32-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.2.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-6.2.0/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw32 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw620/i686-620-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=win32 --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-isl-version-check --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='i686-win32-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw620/i686-620-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw620/i686-620-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/opt/include -I/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe -L/c/mingw620/i686-620-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/opt/lib -L/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw620/prerequisites/i686-w64-mingw32-static/lib -Wl,--large-address-aware'
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.2.0 (i686-win32-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '--version' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/ -U_REENTRANT help-dummy -quiet -dumpbase help-dummy -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase help-dummy -version --version -o C:\Users\AlfP\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4K0l79.s
GNU C11 (i686-win32-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) version 6.2.0 (i686-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 6.2.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version 0.15
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '--version' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v --version -o C:\Users\AlfP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccn2QnTg.o C:\Users\AlfP\AppData\Local\Temp\cc4K0l79.s
GNU assembler version 2.25 (i686-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.25
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `i686-w64-mingw32'.
COMPILER_PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/;C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/;C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/;C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../lib/;C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '--version' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\AlfP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXVaxln.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-liconv -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt --sysroot=C:/mingw620/i686-620-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32 -m i386pe -Bdynamic -u ___register_frame_info -u ___deregister_frame_info --version C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0 -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../.. C:\Users\AlfP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccn2QnTg.o -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -liconv -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/crtend.o
collect2 version 6.2.0
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe -plugin C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\AlfP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXVaxln.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-liconv -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt --sysroot=C:/mingw620/i686-620-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32 -m i386pe -Bdynamic -u ___register_frame_info -u ___deregister_frame_info --version C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0 -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../.. C:\Users\AlfP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccn2QnTg.o -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -liconv -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-6.2.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v5-rev1/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/crtend.o
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.25
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '--version' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'

[C:\my\temp]
> _
```

Comment: @Kos: No. Please double-check what you *believe* before you report it as alleged fact.

Comment: GCC with `-Wall` gives `warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'main' with no type [-Wreturn-type]`, and with `-pedantic-errors`: `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'main' with no type [-Wpedantic]`.

Comment: Just to be clear about the compiler version I'm using, it reports "g++ (i686-win32-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.2.0". Sorry I thought it was 6.3.0. Fixed that now in the question.

Comment: GCC v6.2.0 [on this website generates an error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/nojs/gcc-6.2.0/permlink/fvpTaqi6kESeZFdg) (or a warning if you disable pedantic). Don't know which architecture it runs or whether it's MinGW, but I don't see how that would affect something like this.

Comment: We've already established what applies to commonly used variants of g++, now we're just debugging why it apparently doesn't work with your MinGW. Can you please edit the question and make that clear? I feel it's misleading right now, since normally it's a pretty basic setting.

Comment: @Kos: Your *assertions* are incorrect, as twice before, but I've amended the question. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried on cygwin g++ 5.3 and am seeing similar behavior -- on godbolt 5.3 I get the error, but in cygwin I get no error with -pedantic-errors.  Also I tried specifying c++ 11 and 14 to no avail.

Comment: You should change the title to request answers clearly for the g++ of Mingw. And not -1 everyone who gives an answer about gnu g++.

Because --pedantic-errors crearly works in [gnu's version](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: @user183833 agreed, this would have helped a lot, especially because it still says that it presumes a similar behavior between builds on different platforms.

Comment: @user183833: I am mainly interested in a solution for *all* variants of g++ 6.2.0 and later.

Comment: You did not state this in your initial question, that you a want a solution to work on all variants

Comment: MinGW is a port of GCC that's maintained separately. I feel the questions we should be asking is "why does this particular port behave differently than the upstream in this simple case?".

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Please, can you output your `g++ -v` command and add the output to the question? You seem to have a rather unusual version of GCC.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Done. But I don't think any of that output is relevant. Maybe I'm pessimistic.

Comment: I was talking about the command that display the GCC version with its flags.

Comment: Just a factoid, xaxxon [reproduced the issue in Cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624055/how-to-make-g-require-a-standard-main#comment72376612_42624055) (link is to his comment above), so it's not specific to my installation.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Oh, that's more meaningful, yes! Sorry I'm stupid at times. Updated q with that command output.

Comment: Again sorry, I had a typo in the version command I posted. Fixed that.

Comment: I tried to have a look at the MinGW sources. Maybe I got the wrong version, but it looked like that `-pedantic-errors` check was in there, so all I can think is that the driver isn't passing some option through properly or something.

Comment: @TartanLlama: I think a syntax exception for `main` *has been* in the source code, because [old docs of `-Wreturn-type`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html) say "For C++, a function without return type always produces a diagnostic message, even when -Wno-return-type is specified. The only exceptions are `main' and functions defined in system headers."

Answer (score 8):

You can pass `-pedantic-errors`, which gives the following error message on g++ 6.3:

```
main.cpp:1:6: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'main' with no type [-Wpedantic]
 main(){}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1ac3a207de47b8e)

Here is the documentation for `-pedantic-errors`:

> Give an error whenever the base standard (see -Wpedantic) requires a diagnostic, in some cases where
>              there is undefined behavior at compile-time and in some other cases that do not prevent compilation of
>              programs that are valid according to the standard. This is not equivalent to -Werror=pedantic, since
>              there are errors enabled by this option and not enabled by the latter and vice versa.

Comment: You beat me to it :) I strongly recommend compiling ALL your code with this option.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't see you stating that you've tried `-pedantic-errors` and it didn't work.

Comment: @xaxxon: I somehow doubt that the godbolt site uses MinGW.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "I imagine an answer will apply to all currently used variants of g++"

Comment: @EJP: prove the "all others". Also prove the "we". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Once you enable warnings (`-Wall`), g++ will complain about this code. Additionally you can have the warnings be treated as errors (`-Werror`), so that the compilation fails (a good thing to have).

Example with g++ 5.4.0:

```
kos@Starbuck ~$ cat bar.cpp                                                    
main(){}
kos@Starbuck ~$ g++ bar.cpp                                                    
kos@Starbuck ~$ g++ bar.cpp -Wall -Werror                                      
bar.cpp:1:6: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type [-Werror=return-type]
 main(){}
      ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: It's the actual output from my machine. Can you explain the criteria by which it's incorrect?

Comment: **−1** It's incorrect in the "works on my machine" way. It's not generally true.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the output you get from this exact command on your machine?

Comment: done, some time ago (I didn't see your comment, sorry).